# Hyperlinks are not displaying on xhtml page

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish-3

hyperlinks are not displaying on the page , i deployed on glassfish server.Below is the image.Under products section all are hyperlinks

[image]

below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>

<title>eBusiness</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h1 style="background-color:#4863A0;color:white;">eBusiness: Product, Customer, and Order Management</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<f:view>
<h:form>
<table>
<tr><td><h2>PRODUCTS</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h:outputLink  value="createbook.xhtml">Create a new Book</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="viewbooklist.xhtml">The Stock of Books</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="searchbooks.xhtml">Search for Books</h:outputLink></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<h:outputLink  value="createcds.xhtml">Create a new CDs</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="viewcdslist.xhtml">The Stock of CDs</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="searchcds.xhtml">Search for CDs</h:outputLink></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td><h2>CUSTOMERS</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h:outputLink  value="createcustomer.xhtml">Create a new Customer</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="viewcustomerlist.xhtml">List of Customers</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="searchcustomer.xhtml">Search for a Customers</h:outputLink></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr><td><h2>ORDERS</h2>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h:outputLink  value="createorders.xhtml">Create a new Order</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="vieworderslist.xhtml">List of Orders</h:outputLink>|</td><td><h:outputLink  value="searchorders.xhtml">Search for an Orders</h:outputLink></td>
</tr>
</table>
</h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can anyone let me know what is the reason behind

***Update :***

Not only this all pages are not getting rendered(only html content is displaying).

***EDIT***

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RetailProducts</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>createcustomer.xhtml</welcome-file><!-- eBusiness.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
<!--   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener> -->
<!--     <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener> -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you look in the browser to the HTML source text? If you did not correctly bind the JSF servlet, `h:outputLink` will appear in the HTML.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes h:outputLink is appearing the view source, its not got rendered to html code

Comment: @JoopEggen please can you help this

Comment: Do you have `FacesServlet` mapped to `*.xhtml`? And can you post web.xml? Also, what do you mean by 'only HTML content is displayed'?

Comment: @JoopEggen i posted web.xml above

Comment: From the code I cannot see whether the URLs start with `/faces/create.xhtml` and such. You could try a mapping `*.xhtml`. But the problem seems to be elsewhere. So await the answers.

Comment: `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`?

Comment: Thanks for your if you havent ask the mapping .xhtml question, i will be keep on digging the problem. I added mapping then it is working.

Comment: @downvoters, please provide your valuable comments on downvoting. there is no sense in downvoting without comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding servlet mapping as *.xhtml its working fine

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```